# How do I highlight a whole row based on the condition of a cell in that row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet with customer information in it.  One of our columns for each customer is a date.  I've been trying to figure out a way to have each customer's whole row be highlighted once that date passes.  The date is in column F and spans from cell F2 down to F124.  Here's what I've tried:

```
=TODAY()>$F$2:$F$124
```

I've set that formula to apply to:

```
=$A$2:$O$124
```

However, predictably, that turns the whole sheet blue when one cell evaluates to true.

I see the mistake in what I have done but I can't seem to find my way around it.

Comment: Just write =Today()>F2 while selecting all Data it will move to F3 automatically for other rows

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following formula:
`=Today()>F2`
while selecting each column alone and set the rules and the format you need it will move to F3 automatically for other rows
It is better to select the column and click Conditional Formatting, New Rule, Use Formula to determine which cells to Format, write the formula above and choose the Format
Repeat with the same Formula (do not change) for the following column one at a time
**Update**
You can select all and use the following as "gtwebb" suggested:
=Today()>$F2
and format as you like it will change automatically for each Row

Comment: You can just freeze the column in the formula `=Today()>$F2` and apply it to all cells at the same time

Comment: That is kind of a "Band-Aid" and while I appreciate the answer - and it is an answer - I'm looking for a way to do it with one conditional, not one conditional for each column.

Comment: Updated the Formula as "gtwebb" mentioned and it works

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar on a few of my spreadsheets.  In my case, I've got a table where each row is another date (all sorted in increasing date order).  I use conditional formatting to make the lower border of a row of cells turn blue for the last day of each month.  To do this, I apply this formula:

```
=MONTH(INDIRECT("B"&ROW()))<MONTH(INDIRECT("B"&ROW()+1))
```

to the entire range of my table (column B has the date).  It compares the month for the current row with the month for the next row, using the INDIRECT formula to construct a cell reference from a string representation.

In your case, applying that concept to your problem should result in a formula like

```
=TODAY()>INDIRECT("F"&ROW())
```

The advantage of this approach is that you don't need a separate conditional formula for every row of the table - you can use a single formula applied to the entire table.  I don't think it will run any faster, but it should be easier to maintain, should you need to change the conditional formatting in the future.